# How to pass array parameter. Drizzle

Tags: web3js, truffle, arrays, abi, drizzle

Is there have a way to pass array parameter from the drizzle to my contract ?
I want to pass an array of uint[]

[image: my contract]

i have read a lot about getData() function and encodeABI but how to use it in Drizzle ?